# How to get offset of a matched an n-gram in text

Tags: python, text-mining, string-matching, n-gram

I would like to match a string ( n-gram) in a text, with a way to get offsets with it :

`string_to_match = "many workers are very underpaid" 
 text = "The new york times claimed in a report that many workers are very underpaid in some africans countries."`

so as result I want to get a tuple like this `("matched", 44, 75)` where 44 is the start and 75 is the end occurrence.

here is the code I have build, but it works only for unigram.

```
def extract_offsets(line, _len=len):
    words = line.split()
    index = line.index
    offsets = []
    append = offsets.append
    running_offset = 0
    for word in words:
        word_offset = index(word, running_offset)
        word_len = _len(word)
        running_offset = word_offset + word_len
        append(("matched", word_offset, running_offset - 1))
    return offsets

def get_entities(offsets):
    entities = []
    for elm in offsets:
        if elm[0] == "string_to_match": # here string_to_match is only one word
            entities.append(elm)
    return entities

offsets = extract_offsets(text)
entities = get_entities(offsets) # [("matched", start, end)]
```

any tips to make that work for sequence of strings or n-grams!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `re.finditer()` and call `span()` method on the matched object to get the beginning and the ending indices of the matched substring-

```
def m():
    string_to_match = "many workers are very underpaid"
    text = "The new york times claimed in a report that many workers are very underpaid in some africans countries."
    m = re.finditer(r'%s'%(string_to_match),text)
    for x in m:
        print x.group(0), x.span()     # x.span() will return the beginning and the ending indices of the matched substring as a tuple
```